# error creating a new ec2 volume with ansible

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

I am using ansible 2.1.0.  When I try to use ec2_vol to create a new volume, the error I get is 'Volume' object has not attribute 'encrypted'.  The trace is:

```
An exception occurred during task execution. The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ansible_QgknUu/ansible_module_ec2_vol.py", line 593, in <module>
    main()
  File "/tmp/ansible_QgknUu/ansible_module_ec2_vol.py", line 583, in main
    volume_info = get_volume_info(volume, state)
  File "/tmp/ansible_QgknUu/ansible_module_ec2_vol.py", line 454, in get_volume_info
    'encrypted': volume.encrypted,
AttributeError: 'Volume' object has no attribute 'encrypted'
```

Has anyone else seen this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My issue was related to the fact that my version of python boto was not compatible with the ansible version I was using.  Using apt-get in Ubuntu install version 2.20, and I think I need at least 2.30.  So I used pip to install boto

```
pip install boto
```

An everything is fine now.

Comment: The answer is correct. To run upgrade, `sudo pip install -U boto`